# Modify website MSBuild options to include configuration in path

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I'm in the process of updating an old solution from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2015, and I'm trying to reproduce as much of our old kludgy behavior as we safely can to minimize the downstream effects.  I'm currently running into an issue with the Website Property Pages and MSBuild.

[image: Website properties dialog]

The path here is mostly correct, except that we want the configuration used to be in the path as well.  So a `Debug` build will go into `E:\Projects\...\PrecompiledWeb\Debug\MyService` and a `Release` build will go into `E:\Projects\...\PrecompiledWeb\Release\MyService`.  Is this doable?  Is there a variable I can insert to make that determination when building?

We're using `msbuild` against the containing solution file (via TeamCity if it matters, but I can replicate it without it).

**Edit:** I've found the `Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath` and `Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath` paths in the solution, but if I change them to be separate, the Debug one overrides the Release one when I next open the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

When MSBuild starts building the project, it takes one or several project files. This dialog takes it parameters from MSBuild project file (you can edit it either from Visual Studio, or simply in every text editor). The project should have the property, called **$(Configuration)**. You can use it in your output variable:

```
<OutputPath>E:\Projects\...\PrecompiledWeb\$(Configuration)\MyService</OutputPath>
```

One thing you must aware of is that the property **$(Configuration)** must be declared before the **$(OutputPath)** property.

Comment: Website projects don't actually have project files.  The solution might be to convert it to a webapp, which does, but that's a bigger change than I was hoping to make.